# Selecting iPhoto images within a cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, imagekit

I was wondering what the best way of selecting photos from iPhoto within a cocoa application? Right now, the open file dialogue doesn't allow me to go into the iPhoto library. How can I allow the user to go into that folder? IKPictureTaker was one option, but it appears that it allows the selection of one picture at a time. I'd like a user to be able to select 1 picture, or many.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `NSOpenPanel` and set the allowed file types to the `public.image` UTI:

```
[panel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.image"]];
```

This will automatically add a **Media** section and **Photos** item to the sidebar in the open panel that allows the user to select from their iPhoto library.

Alternatively, you can use Karelia's open-source [iMedia Browser](https://github.com/karelia/imedia).

Comment: @Rob i just have to do it but it didn't work i can not access iphoto lobrary

Comment: @Rob i have to do [panel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.image"]]; still it is disable for iphoto library

Answer (score 0):

There is a private API of Apple that contains exactly the control you want; this control is an **ILMediaBrowserView** and provides **the exact same view than the one in NSOpenDialog**.

**If you are planning an AppStore release of your app don't use it** but it can be useful.

The framework to integrate to your project to get that view is **iLifeMediaBrowser.framework** in **/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks**.

Let's all hope Apple brings the same view in the documented IK.